# Rate of change when function f changes from3 to 3.2

Tags: calculus

If the change in the function f when X changes from 3 to 3.2 equals 4.2, then the average change of the function equals ....  a) 0.48 b) 4 c)4.4 d) 21
Can someone solve this while displaying the steps needed?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Could you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average change of the function is

$$A=\frac {\Delta f}{\Delta x} .$$

with $$\Delta x=3.2-3=0.2$$
and
$$\Delta f=4.2,$$

we find $$A=21$$